# How to handle a Custom Connector that uses header authentication in each API call?

Tags: azure, security, authentication, azure-logic-apps, connector

I have an Azure logic app that uses a Custom Connector that I've made from importing a Postman Collection. The RESTful API that my connector calls require 3 authentication headers in each request: `UserName`, `Secret`, `ApiIntegrationCode`. Because it takes three specifically named parameters, I don't believe that any of the authentication presets will work for me.

I know that I can protect the inputs and outputs of various connectors. I have been entertaining the idea of storing the sensitive information in a SQL table that I query in each run and storing the values in variables that I pass to each of my custom connector's API calls.

Would this be a viable way of protecting sensitive data from being seen by people that may have access to my logic app? What is the most secure way I can pass these headers in each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not too many options within a (consumption) Logic App in this regard.

#### Your options with Logic Apps

A first step into the right direction is to put your sensitive information into an [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts) and use [the corresponding connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/keyvault/) in your Logic App to retrieve the data from there. This is easier to implement and more secure than querying a SQL table for this purpose.

The second thing you can do is to activate [secure inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#secure-data-in-run-history-by-using-obfuscation) for the connectors that make the API calls. This makes sure, that the sensitive information passed to these connectors is obfuscated in the run history of your logic App and in connected services like Azure Log Analytics.

The problem with this approach is, that anyone who has more than just read permissions to your Logic App can just go ahead and deactivate the secure inputs setting or create a step that dumps the content of your Key Vault. You can use [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) to control access to your Logic App but that means of course administrative overhead.

#### Alternative: API Management Service

If you want by all means to allow other developers to change the Logic App without exposing API secrets to them, you might consider using some sort of middle tier to communicate with the API. [Azure API Management Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) (APIM) is one of the options here.

You would manage your sensitive information in a Key Vault and inject them via "Named Values" into your APIM instance. You can then add your API as a backend in APIM and expose it towards your Logic App.

The advantage here is that you can secure access to your API with APIM [subscription keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions) that you can cycle frequently. You can also restrict the access to the original API to only those calls, that need to be available to the Logic App.

If APIM is something for you depends on your use case, as it comes at a price. Even the developer plan costs about $50/month: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/

#### Alternative: Azure Function

You can use a simple [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) that serves as a middle tier between your Logic App and your API. This function can be configured to pull the sensitive data from a Key Vault and can also be secured via a [function access key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts#function-access-keys), that you can renew on a regular basis.

This is a dirt cheap option, if you are running the functions on a consumption plan: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/